# Bimolecular recombination: How can it be non-radiative for $e$-$p$ pair?

Tags: solid-state-physics, education, molecules, solar-cells, quasiparticles

I have understood that the bimolecular recombination of electrons and holes can be radiative when they meet each other,

However, I also heard that there are defect sites that can accept electrons and holes together but not individually, thus this is the source of nonradiative bimolecular recombination,

Can someone explain to me what is the nature of those defects? I am confused, what kind of defect can only happen when e and hole find each other,

Here is the reference for the answer I am talking about:

[Bimolecular recombination in few words](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/180893/)